# Rails Select Tag - passing an argument to controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Recently I've encountered a problem with passing parameters from view to the controller using select tag. Here is the code:

/app/views/admins/heimdall.html.erb

```
<%= select_tag 'users',options_from_collection_for_select(User.where(id: @users.ids), "id", "email", params[:users].blank? ? current_user.id : params[:users]), :onchange => "this.form.submit();", class: 'form-control pull-right' %>
```

What I want is to pass the ID of the chosen user to the hash params in order to reload the page again, this time with the chosen user data.

In console I got this error:

heimdall:280 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of null

I will be very happy, if u help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please be make sure `select_tag` added inside `form_tag` or `form_for` view helper.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, indeed form tag was needed, problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `this.form` is `undefined`, because the `js code` is executed in document context, which doesn't have `form` property.

You can submit the form by using `jquery` selector `$("form").submit()` or maybe `$("#email").parent("form").submit()` if you have multiple forms and want to submit the form containing the `email` field.